# LinkedIn Organization Share Statistics API not returning aggregated statistics

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn's API V2 docs for the Organization Share Statistics endpoint list some aggregated statistic fields in the response schema

- shareStatisticsByCountry
- shareStatisticsByDegree
- shareStatisticsByFunction
- shareStatisticsByIndustry
- shareStatisticsBySeniority
- shareStatisticsByStaffCountRange

API link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics

But I can't seem to get them in the response, either in a lifetime query or in a time range query. Their sample response JSON don't show those fields either.

My query

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3Axxxxxxx&q=organizationalEntity
```

The response I get

```
{"elements"=>
  [{"total_share_statistics"=>
     {"share_count"=>328,
      "unique_impressions_count"=>36098,
      "click_count"=>2451,
      "engagement"=>0.044408163265306125,
      "share_mentions_count"=>67,
      "like_count"=>1000,
      "impression_count"=>85750,
      "comment_mentions_count"=>14,
      "comment_count"=>29},
    "organizational_entity"=>"urn:li:organization:xxxxxxx"}],
 "paging"=>{"count"=>10, "start"=>0, "links"=>[]}}
```

Is there some parameters I'm missing? Or does the organization I'm querying simply don't have enough engagement on its shares?

Answer (score 0):

Basically those fields do not exist anymore. I got the following answer from the Linkedin technical support on their Zendesk about this issue.

> Apologies for the confusion. Those fields are actually no longer available in the API. We have a pending documentation change to remove those from that page.